# HTML5 Canvas broken in Chrome 44.0.2403.125 m

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

Canvas stroke() seems to be broken in chrome version 44
see test: https://jsfiddle.net/n9ds4q8m/ click on test button
works fine in FF/IE even Edge. Grid does not show in Chrome but used to?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawing");
        //  if the canvas element exists 
        if (canvas != null) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.setLineDash([null]);
            ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#eeeeee";

            // horizontal grid lines
            for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i = i + 10) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, i);
                ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
                if (i % parseInt(50) == 0) {
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                } else {
                    ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
                }
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            // vertical grid lines
            for (var j = 0; j <= canvas.width; j = j + 10) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(j, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(j, canvas.height);
                if (j % parseInt(50) == 0) {
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                } else {
                    ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
                }
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            }

        }

    }
```

HTML: `<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><input type="button" onclick="draw()" value="test" />
        <canvas id="drawing" width="800" height="550" style="position: relative; cursor: crosshair; border: 1px solid #000; z-index: 10; -ms-touch-action: none; touch-action: none;"></canvas>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you noticed this. I sort of noticed this a few days ago, but didn't set out to really investigate it until today. I have narrowed down the problem. It doesn't like the 
    `ctx.setLineDash([null]);`
part. In my code, I was using 
    `ctx.setLineDash([0,0]);` and it doesn't like that either.

After some more investigating, it seems that [0,0] doesn't make any sense, even though Firefox allows it that way. Also, [null] isn't spec compliant. So the best way to make solid lines is 
    `ctx.setLineDash([]);`